# How to calculate the ScreenSize exactly under the consideration of Samsung Galaxy Edge in android

Tags: android, keyboard, resolution, dimension

How can I calculate the screen size exactly under the consideration of Edge part?
Now, I'm developing custom keyboard and when it becomes visible, its size is calculated programmatically based on screen size.

What function I used calculate the screen size is like following.

```
public static Point getDimentionalSize(Context context)
{
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    int realWidth;
    int realHeight;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
        //new pleasant way to get real metrics
        DisplayMetrics realMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getRealMetrics(realMetrics);
        realWidth = realMetrics.widthPixels;
        realHeight = realMetrics.heightPixels;

    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        //reflection for this weird in-between time
        try {
            Method mGetRawH = Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight");
            Method mGetRawW = Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth");
            realWidth = (Integer) mGetRawW.invoke(display);
            realHeight = (Integer) mGetRawH.invoke(display);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //this may not be 100% accurate, but it's all we've got
            realWidth = display.getWidth();
            realHeight = display.getHeight();
            Log.e("Display Info", "Couldn't use reflection to get the real display metrics.");
        }

    } else {
        //This should be close, as lower API devices should not have window navigation bars
        realWidth = display.getWidth();
        realHeight = display.getHeight();
    }

    return new Point(realWidth, realHeight);
}
```

This function calculates screen size exactly in terms of pixels.
But when I try it on `Samsung Galaxy Note Edge`, the resulted screen width composes device's `Edge part` also.
I'd like to exclude it from screen size. (if portrait, from width, otherwise, from height)

What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
I tried but it doesn't work, either.